# Como agregar más tareas a la lista

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Tengo una lista con tareas y necesito que al oprimir enter se agregue la nueva tarea ingresada en el inṕut una vez se oprima enter.

He tratado de hacer definiedo los siguiente pero no me funciona.

---

### app.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input').keyup(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode == 13)
      {
        var valorTexto = $(this).text();
        $("ul li:last").after( '<li'> + valorTexto)
      }
   });
```

});

---

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Más tareas</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="list">
      <h3>Por hacer:</h3>
      <ul class="todo">
        <li>Sacar la ropa</li>
        <li>Hacer la cama</li>
        <li>Leer un rato</li>
      </ul>
      <input type="text" id="new-task" placeholder="Ingresa una tarea y oprime Enter">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- incluye acá jQuery y crea la referencia a app.js -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### style.css

body {
       font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   }

```
.list {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 330px;

  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 50px;
}

ul {
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #f5f5f2;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #DBDBD3;
}

ul li {
  color: #66665D;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBD3;
}

ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

input[type=text] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 13px;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hice algunas modificaciones a tu código Javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#new-task').keyup(function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode === 13 || e.which === 13) {
        var $valorTexto = $(this).val();
        $(".todo li:last").after('<li>' + $valorTexto + '</li>');
      }
   });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Como puedo blanquear el input para que no quede con el último dato agregado a la lista. El código que se adapta a lo que necesito es el que maneja el evento del enter ya que el ejercicio no me permite utilizar el evento click. Ya realice varias pruebas y ninguna me funcionó, entre ellas $('#input').val('');.

Comment: Intenta con: `$(this).val('')`;

Comment: Había referenciado de manera equivocada el id del input, ya quedó    solucionado con   $('#new-task').val('');

Answer (score 0):

En tu archivo JS o donde escribes tu código javascript/Jquery.

Modificalo por esto

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnAgregarTarea").click(function(){
     var elementoLista = $("#new-task").val();
        $("ol").append("<li>"+ elementoLista +"</li>");
    });
});
```

con `var elementoLista = $("#new-task").val()` recogemos el valor del `input` con id `new-task`  , y con `$("ol").append("<li>"+ elementoLista +"</li>");` Lo agregamos a la lista.

Aquí te dejo el código completo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnAgregarTarea").click(function(){
     var elementoLista = $("#new-task").val();
        $("ol").append("<li>"+ elementoLista +"</li>");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="new-task" placeholder="Ingrese nueva tarea">

<ol>
  <li>Tarea 1</li>
  <li>Tarea 2</li>
  <li>Tarea 3</li>
</ol>

<button id="btnAgregarTarea">Agregar Tarea</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.